# Population with any JS object in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an arbitrary js object as :

```
{
 createdBy : ObjectId('some_id'),
 project : ObjectId('some_id'),
 remarks : <string>
}
```

which does not belong to any schema.

I have two collection project and user.

Lets assume that in above js object, createdBy field should be some ObjectId of a document in user collection(with fields username, fullName in its schema) and project field should be some ObjectId of project document in project collection (with field key and name in its schema).

Now the above object is not an schema nor having references,

I want to populate the above object so as to result into following

```
{
 createdBy : {
    _id : ObjectIdOfRefUserDocument,
    username : 'username',
    fullName : 'users_full_name'
  },
  project : {
    _id : ObjectIdOfRefProjectDocument,
    name : 'project_name',
    key : 'project_key'
  },
  remarks : <some string>
}
```

How do i populate the above object in the easiest way.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Model.populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) to populate plain objects:

```js
var obj = {
  createdBy : ObjectId('some_id'),
  project : ObjectId('some_id'),
  remarks : <string>
};

User.populate(obj, { path: 'createdBy' }, function(err, obj) {
  Project.populate(obj, { path: 'project' }, function(err, obj) {
    // obj's createdBy and project fields are both populated.
  });
});
```